# Making a mobile drop down menu with scroll function?

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile, menu

So I'm working on a website and in particular the mobile version. I have made a "drop down" menu that slides down when the user clicks on the "navicon". And also when the user clicks the "navicon" the website scrolls down to the actual "navicon" image to make the mobile navigation smoother and faster. Now I can't figure out a way (nor find the answer anywhere) to make not only the scroll feature only work when the menu slides down and not up. But I also want the menu items to close the menu whenever you click on them. Any help?

Here's my code:

<-------------------------HTML------------------------->

```
<div class="naviconbutton displaydesktop displaytablet" id="navbutton">

<img src="sitefiles/img/navicon-black.png" alt="navicon" class="navicon">

</div>

<nav class="displaydesktop displaytablet">

<ul id="menu-m">

<li class="click click1"> Menu 1 </li>

<li class="click click2"> Menu 2 </li>

<li class="click click3"> Menu 3 </li>

<li class="click click4"> Menu 4 </li>

</ul>

</nav>
```

<-------------------------CSS------------------------->

```
.naviconbutton {
background:#ddd;
width:100%;
opacity:0.3;
float:left;
margin:20px 0 0 0;
padding:20px 0 20px 0;
}

.naviconbutton .navicon {
display:block;
margin:0 auto;
width:10%;
padding:0;
}

#menu-m {
overflow:hidden;
float:left;
background:#eee;
width:100%;
list-style:none;
padding:0;
margin:0;
height:0px;

-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 15px #999999;
-moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 15px #999999;
-ms-box-shadow:inset 0 0 15px #999999;
box-shadow:inset 0 0 15px #999999;

-webkit-transition:height ease 0.3s;
-moz-transition:height ease 0.3s;
-ms-transition:height ease 0.3s;
transition:height ease 0.3s;
}

#menu-m.slide {
height:313px;
}

#menu-m li {
display:block;
width:100%;
float:left;
padding:30px;
text-align:center;
font-family:"Lato";
font-weight:300;
font-size:15px;

-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
-ms-box-sizing:border-box;
box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

<-------------------------JQUERY------------------------->

```
$(".naviconbutton").click(function(){
$("#menu-m").toggleClass("slide");
$("html, body").animate({
scrollTop: $("#navbutton").offset().top
}, 400);
});

$(".click").click(function(){
$("#menu-m").removeClass("slide");
});

$(".click1").click(function(){
$("html, body").animate({
scrollTop:("600px")
}, 400);
});
```

Comment: you need some onClick event so when you click a menu item the menu has to close automatically am i right?

Comment: Yes exactly! So the menu items first closes the menu and then scrolls down to a certain point!